# How can show my images style from editor

Tags: editor

I have problem when edit an news in post editor, and set the images from editor align left and open site, i cannot see the image in left said.

How can set the post style from editor not from style

Comment: Maybe the theme you use does not have `css` **definitons** for the `alignleft` class that the added image has.

Comment: no i add it ,,, any solution

Comment: Write the code that you added :)

Answer (score 0):

> [add_editor_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style) allows theme developers to link a custom stylesheet file to the TinyMCE visual editor.

You'll want to duplicate many (if not all) of your styles from the front-end to be included in that file. Then editing in the visual editor will look more like your front-end css.

The problem is more likely that you don't have a `alignleft` class in your front-end stylesheet. [wp_print_styles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_styles) will give you an opportunity to add custom inlined styles.

```
add_action('wp_print_styles', function() { ?>
<style>
    /**
     * 4.0 - Alignment
     */

    .alignleft {
        float: left !important;
        margin: 6px 28px 28px 0;
    }

    .alignright {
        float: right !important;
        margin: 6px 0 28px 28px;
    }
</style>
<?php
});
```

If you literally want to put the editor styles on the front-end (which nobody said ever) then just [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style).

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_style('editor-styles', includes_url('/css/editor.css'));
});
```